# ¿Cómo aplico QuickSort a dos colecciones?

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento, colecciones

Tengo una coleccion de placas de vehiculos y otra de indices de dichas placas. Lo que tengo que hacer es aplicarle ordenamiento QuickSort a la coleccion de placas (String) y a su vez que se muevan los indices para que queden junto a su placa correspondiente; es decir no debo aplicarle nuevamente el ordenamiento a los indices sino que solo moverlos junto a las placas. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public static void QuickSort(ArrayList<String> colPlacas, ArrayList<Object> colPosiciones, int izq, int der) {
    String pivote = colPlacas.get(izq);
    int i = izq;
    int j = der;
    Object aux,aux2;

    while (i < j) {
        while (colPlacas.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(pivote) <= 0 && i < j) {
            i++;
        }
        while (colPlacas.get(j).compareToIgnoreCase(pivote) > 0) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            aux = colPlacas.get(i);
            colPlacas.set(i, colPlacas.get(j));
            colPlacas.set(j, String.valueOf(aux));    
        }

    }
    /* Se supone que con estas tres lineas se mueven los indices a la pos de su placa 
       correspondiente*/
    aux2 = colPosiciones.get(i);
    colPosiciones.set(i, colPosiciones.get(j));
    colPosiciones.set(j, aux2);
    /* fin movimiento de indices*/

    colPlacas.set(izq, colPlacas.get(j)); // ya esto hace parte del quicksort
    colPlacas.set(j, pivote);

    if (izq < j - 1) {
        QuickSort(colPlacas, colPosiciones, izq, j - 1);
    }
    if (j + 1 < der) {
        QuickSort(colPlacas, colPosiciones, j + 1, der);
    }

}
```

Mi input es el siguiente:

```
ABC123   0
JKL257   25
EEE234   48
```

El output esperando seria:

```
ABC123  0
EEE234  48
JKL257  25
```

Pero con el codigo tal cual como está, recibo lo siguiente:

```
ABC123  25
EEE234  0
JKL257  48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que solo estas modificando un array, piensa que se van a modificar los dos de la misma forma

```
 public static void QuickSort(ArrayList<String> colPlacas, ArrayList<Object> colPosiciones, int izq, int der) {
        String pivote = colPlacas.get(izq);
        Object pivotePosiciones = colPosiciones.get(izq);
        int i = izq;
        int j = der;
        Object aux, aux2;

        while (i < j) {
            while (colPlacas.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(pivote) <= 0 && i < j) {
                i++;
            }
            while (colPlacas.get(j).compareToIgnoreCase(pivote) > 0) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                aux = colPlacas.get(i);
                colPlacas.set(i, colPlacas.get(j));
                colPlacas.set(j, String.valueOf(aux));

                aux2 = colPosiciones.get(i);
                colPosiciones.set(i, colPosiciones.get(j));
                colPosiciones.set(j, aux2);
            }

        }

        colPosiciones.set(izq, colPosiciones.get(j));
        colPosiciones.set(j, pivotePosiciones);

        colPlacas.set(izq, colPlacas.get(j)); 
        colPlacas.set(j, pivote);

        if (izq < j - 1) {
            QuickSort(colPlacas, colPosiciones, izq, j - 1);
        }
        if (j + 1 < der) {
            QuickSort(colPlacas, colPosiciones, j + 1, der);
        }

    }
```